# Swift type-check takes long time

Tags: swift, xcode

I've added the flag `-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=50` to my Swift project to see what is taking too long. I've the following 
expression:

```
let s: String = "1234"
let t: Int? = Int(s)
```

On the `Int(s)` I get the warning `Expression took 52ms to type-check (limit: 50ms)`. I'm just wondering why this takes more than 50ms to figure out since I specified all types.

Comment: When you downvote, please explain why so I can possible improve my question. Or maybe this is just a dumb question?

Comment: You shouldn't really "simplify down" your code when your problem is about complex expressions...

Comment: @Sweeper the code I've pasted gives me the warning. I've changed the code to focus on the problem and remove some of the noise around it, but most important the warning will given using this exact code. I will use a different word in my question (removed the simplified, because it didn't make sense and causes confusion).

Comment: Try to see if this is faster `let t: Int? = Int(s, radix: 10)`?

Comment: @zaitsman Yes that compiles under 5 ms!

Comment: Coolio, so my looking at `Int()` initializers in the code completion, i can see there are a couple that take a `String` so my guess is the compiler is just trying to resolve one based on arguments and returning `Int?` and that takes longer; what we did when we supplied `radix` was limit the number of possible choices. That's purely my speculation, of course!

Comment: @zaitsman sounds logical to me though and probably the best explanation we are going to get without knowing the full in and outs of the Swift compiler. Maybe post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we try to run this initializer:

`let t: Int? = Int(s, radix: 10)`

we can see that the typecheck is a lot faster.

Looking at `Int` initializers in the code completion, i can see there are a couple that take a `String`, so my guess is the compiler is just trying to resolve one based on arguments and returning `Int?` and that takes longer

What we did when we supplied radix was limit the number of possible choices, which is why that code typecheck is faster. That's purely my speculation, of course!