# How does the Swift compiler choose between two Int initializers with a String parameter?

Tags: swift, clang, swift-compiler

I recently found an `Int` initializer:

```swift
init?<S>(_ text: S, radix: Int = 10) where S: StringProtocol
```

As you can see, the second parameter `radix` has a default value with 10, so I can call this function without providing it.

Meanwhile, `String` does conform to this `StringProtocol` through the following extension:

```swift
extension String : StringProtocol { 
    //... 
}
```

And there is another initializer for `Int`:

```swift
init?(_ description: String)
```

Given the code:

```swift
let x = Int("123")
```

How could the Swift compiler know which initializer to call as this statement matches both of them. What factors influence its decision-making process?

Comment: What difference would it make? In the absence of a radix the answer is 123 either way.

Comment: type-checking time consumption may differ.@matt
check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57302881/swift-type-check-takes-long-time

Comment: There is a lot of things that it considers. I think this might be too broad. In your specific case, it's because "leaving out optional parameters" is better than "*not* leaving out optional parameters".

Comment: So Swift is open source. Why not look at the code and see?

Comment: You‘re right. I shouldn't try the easy way.

Comment: If you write it as `let x = Int.init("123")` then you can use Xcode's “jump to definition” feature to see which method is invoked, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/32048978/1187415